# How to get encoding time per frame using x265 v1.7?

Tags: hevc, libx265

Using `-log-level 4` on x265 `v1.4` I get encoding time and elapsed time per frame.

Now using `v1.7` I don't get these values in csv. Instead I get  `DecideWait (ms),   Row0Wait (ms), Wall time (ms), Ref Wait Wall (ms), Total CTU time (ms), Stall Time (ms), Avg WPP,  amd Row Blocks`.

I tried `-log-level` values 3,4 and 5 and still no luck.

can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

x265 v2.5 now gives the Total frame time (ms) in the csv log file.

When you run an x265 encoding add the following flag and csv created file location:

```
--csv-log-level 2 --csv info.csv
```

More info can be found [here](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/x265/stable/x265.pdf) and [here](http://x265.readthedocs.io/en/default/cli.html#cmdoption-csv).

For x265 earlier versions, a rough estimation of the elapsed time per frame is calculated by the summation of `DecideWait (ms), Row0Wait (ms), and Wall time (ms)`.